# Unable to find element using relative xpath

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, xpath

I am currently trying to use xpath to locate the element for my selenium project, why is that when I try to run the selenium it is unable to locate the element with a relative path even though it's unique to the DOM? My goal is to use the title attribute of a div tag to locate the element since the div tags are very dynamic.

Absolute Path

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[8]/div[1]/div[3]/div[5]
```

Relative Path that is unique

```
//*//div[@title='This is the title ']
```

Comment: Post the relevant html.

Comment: Don't know without seeing the HTML, but your example of a "relative path" is actually an absolute path. Anything starting with "/" or "//" starts its selection at the root of the document, and is by definition an absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use

```
//*[@title='This is the title ']
```

Instead of

```
//*//div[@title='This is the title ']
```

Indeed, `//*` directly locate the element in all child nodes.

Comment: `//*div` is not valid xpath.